# Как получить доступ из моего класса к экземпляру окна в WPF?

Tags: wpf, c#

Собственно хотелось бы обратится к элементам UI главного окна приложения, только вот непонятно каким образом. Понятное дело, что из самого класса окна к контролам легко получить доступ, а вот чтобы из стороннего - непонятно как. (Передавать их по ссылке не годится).

Передавать контролы или само окно в класс по ссылке не годится, так как в нём есть методы, которые должны асинхронно выполняться с обработчиками окна. Есть ли какой-то ещё способ? В противном случае придётся использовать ISynchronizeInvoke, а этого хотелось бы избежать.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какая структура у приложения. Вы используете MVVM или другой шаблон?

Comment: Нет, у меня событийная модель.

Comment: Из вопроса не совсем ясно, о чем идет речь. Не могли бы вы привести участок кода с асинхронными вызовами?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Передавать контролы по ссылкам, конечно, не стоит. Нужно создать event в главном окне и уведомлять его через этот event о необходимости изменения контролов. Это если в одном потоке находятся главное окно и тот, кто посылает ему уведомление.

```
// Какой то класс
public class MyClass
{
    public event MyDelegate MyDelegateEvent; // Ваш евент
    public void f()
    {
        // При вызове функции f() уведомляем главное окно (и всех кто подпишется на него)
        MyDelegateEvent();
    }
}

public delegate void MyDelegate(); // Делегат

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyClass my = new MyClass(); // Это просто создание нашего класса
        // Создаем наше уведомление
        my.MyDelegateEvent += new MyDelegate(my_MyDelegateEvent);
    }

    void my_MyDelegateEvent()
    {
      // Изменяем нужные контролы
    }
}
```

Comment: если можно - немножко подробнее, повозможности с участком кода

Comment: @alvin обновил ответ